# FULL OUTER JOIN stuck if two join fields is using in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have issues with FULL OUTER JOIN
Query:

```
SELECT
  count(e.id)
FROM 
  eligibility e 
FULL OUTER JOIN
  tr_entry t
    ON t.correlation_id2 = e.correlation_id2
    OR t.correlation_id = e.correlation_id
WHERE (
        (t.correlation_id IS NULL AND t.correlation_id2 IS NULL)
    OR
        (e.correlation_id IS NULL AND e.correlation_id2 IS NULL)
    ) 
    and e.PAIRING_DATE is NULL
    AND t.PAIRING_DATE IS NULL
;
```

Query just stuck and I have to restart Oracle. On small dataset all is ok, but when a dataset is big (more than 1 million records in eligibility table) DB is stuck. Which index I have to use on both table?

Comment: Your formatting and indentation was insane  *(I'm also dubious about your brackets in the WHERE clause...)*  If you want people to read your code please format it in a manner that makes doing so less than agonising.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  Your query isn't the easiest to follow.  You are only selecting columns from one table, so a `full outer join` doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: So you are trying to find all `eligibility` records that have no match in `tr_entry` and vice versa? But you are only displaying `eligibility` columns. That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: You have to _restart Oracle_? Or you just have to cancel the query? By "stuck" do you mean "very slow"?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, I'm trying to find just all eligibility records that have no match in tr_entry

Comment: @WilliamRobertson just don't respond, I have to cancel the query

Comment: Example data will help a lot here.  For example, are the `IS NULL` conditions in the `WHERE` clause to represent "where there was no successful join" or to represent "where the data in the table actually has a NULL in that column"?  There are many other ambiguities that a query alone would never be able to communicate.  Giving us example data *(both input and output)* will demonstrate to us what the query ***is*** doing, what it ***isn't*** doing, and allow us to give recommendations on different optimisations.

Answer (score 2):

Your comment:

> Yes, I'm trying to find just all eligibility records that have no match in tr_entry

So why a full outer join? That makes no sense. You should use a `NOT EXISTS` clause instead:

```
select *
from eligibility e
where not exists
(
  select *
  from tr_entry t
  where t.correlation_id  = e.correlation_id
     or t.correlation_id2 = e.correlation_id2
);
```

I don't know how the `pairing_date` columns come into play, so simply put them in the query as you want them :-)